# When do trees grow in SMP servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

SMP servers run continuously. Does that mean that trees (and cacti, and sugar canes, and crops) grow always, even when no one is online? or do they only grow if their chunks are loaded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe they actually have to be loaded in memory, going by [this page from the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trees):

> Trees will only grow if they are
> planted on a chunk of the map that is
> loaded into memory. If you plant
> saplings and then explore another more
> distant area of your world for a few
> Minecraft days, they will still be
> saplings when you return.

Comment: And when are they loaded into memory? Only when someone is online?

Comment: @Denilson Sa -- Yes. It means at least one person is within the however many chunk-radius the game uses at a time.

Comment: Don't forget that you could get Bukkit and use a world-anchor.